# Expected sum value of permutaion

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, permutations, random-variables, expectation

We have a **set(A)** of **N elements**. Let's assume elements are `e1,e2,e3..`etc.  Value of each element can be **0** or **1**. Another set of N elements(set B) are given, `p1,p2,p3..`etc. Where `p (i) =probability of e (i) to be 1`. If we pick a random permutation **P** of **N** elements from **set(A)**. What is the expected sum of elements in **P** ?

Example : if set(A) contains 5 elements `e1,e2,e3,e4,e5` and we picked a 5 element sequence `1,0,0,1,1`. In this case **`sum`** = 3.
`Expected_Value` of **`sum`** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i=1$ to $N$, define random variable $X_i$ by $X_i=1$ if the $i$-th element of the permuted sequence has value $1$, and by $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then $Y=X_1+\cdots+X_N$ is the number of $1$'s, and $E(Y)=E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_N)=NE(X_1)$.

By symmetry $E(X_1)=\frac{1}{N}(p_1+\cdots +p_N)$, so $E(Y)=p_1+\cdots+p_N$.

Comment: Thanks. I also did the exact same same way. Actually I found a similar type of question of finding no of local right to left maxima in a permutation of N elements. In Knuth book (vol 3 page 12) is was explained using inversion table. Similarity was like this : whenever a inversion table entry becomes maximal no of local right to left maxima in the selected permutation increases by 1. And they found the expected no of right to left maxima = sum of probabilities of inversion table entries to be maximal. This question was more generic version of that.

Comment: @Debashish: Indicator random variables are indeed a very useful tool.